# TabBar Controller not rotate when a ModalViewController is presented

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, rotation

I'm presenting a UIViewController as Modal from a TabBarController like this (The Controller has a custom shape so I need it the background to be visible):

```
SubsInfoViewController * sivc = [[SubsInfoViewController alloc] init];

AppDelegate * delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
delegate.tabBarController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
[delegate.tabBarController presentModalViewController:sivc animated:YES];
```

The problem comes when I rotate the device (Ipad in this case), the modal view controller rotate just fine, but the controller in the back doesn't, it rotates when I dismiss the Modal, which will be fine if my modal would cover the hole screen, but as it makes the background visible, it feels wrong when the rotation happen.

Any Idea?
Thanks!

Comment: Check that the background view doesn't have a `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation` set to NO.

Comment: Can you provide a little more code, showing your implementation?

Comment: @PaulPeelen They all return YES, they rotate fine when there is no modalviewcontroller.

Comment: @JohannesLumpe what piece of code you think could be useful for me to show

Comment: The rest of the function where you are presenting the modal. From which view are you calling this? Did you put an NSLog into shouldRotate... to see if it gets called at all while the modal is visible?